Documentation File From Another Class Library Doesn't Exist in AKS Container
I have a solution that has the following file structure.

├── src
│   ├── Project.Api
│   │   ├── Project.Api.xml
│   │   ├── Project.Api.csproj
│   │   ├── Other files...
│   ├── Project.Business
│   │   ├── Project.Business.xml
│   │   ├── Project.Business.csproj
│   │   ├── Other files...
├── Dockerfile
├── Project.sln


If I debug or publish this solution, the /bin/Debug and /bin/Release folders both have the Project.Api.xml and Project.Business.xml files. However, if I build it using the Dockerfile and deploy it in AKS, the container only contains the Project.Api.xml file. I was able to confirm this by executing the kubectl -n dev exec -it pod-name -- /bin/bash and ls commands. What should I do to include the other documentation file?
EDIT (27.08):
Sampath, I tried your approach with a little bit of changes and I found something strange. When I added the RUN ls -l command, I confirmed that the Project.Business.xml exists, but on the COPY step I encountered the error /Project.Business.xml": not found. Would you know why this has happened?

# other steps omitted for brevity

# Copy the XML documentation files
WORKDIR "/src/Project.Business"
RUN ls -l
COPY ["Project.Business.xml", "/app/publish/"]



check this  docker

@Sampath, I edited my post after trying your solution. Can you check, please?

@Sohlae what is your file set to for the "Copy to output directory" setting?

@cl0ud Do not copy. I changed this to Copy always but it did not fix the problem. Note that until the dotnet build step, the file exists. It's when the dotnet publish is triggered that the file gets lost, meaning it is not copied to the publish folder. This is a different behavior when I run dotnet publish on my machine; the XML file is there. Could the issue be OS-specific? Our pipeline is using Ubuntu.

Can you please add a [mre] (i.e. fully runnable one reproducing the problem, including some csproj files, docker, etc.)?

use COPY ["src/Project.Business/Project.Business.xml", "/app/publish/"]  instead of
COPY ["Project.Business.xml", "/app/publish/"] in your docker file. use absolute path to copy the file
